# Using Angular Material Progress Spinner in index.html

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display Angular Material's progress spinner when the page is initially loading, so I used the following code in my index file:

```
<body >
  <app-root>
      <md-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate">
  </app-root>
</body>
```

When I do this, the spinner does not appear, however if I move the spinner to my app.component.html file, it does appear. Is it possible to get Angular Material progress spinners to work inside the index file? If so, how?

Comment: you can take a look here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400289/angular2-material-progress-circle

Comment: Why don't you just add a component for `Progress spinner ` ? and use it anywhere you want..

Comment: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/bootstrapping-an-application-in-angular reviews Angular bootstrapping. `index.html` loads before Angular and third party dependencies, so components like `mat-spinner` won't be available inside the scope of `<app-root>`. There are ways to include them outside the scope of `<app-root>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803730/how-to-include-the-ts-component-in-index-html-file but they remain after app load. Maybe there is some hack where you can bootstrap MatProgress module before other deps but... a pure CSS solution is probably the best solution here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will never work. Angular is still loading and so is Angular material. You'll need a pure CSS solution to display a spinner before Angular loads.

Some example in your index.html

```
<app-root>
    <div class="app-loading">
      <div class="logo"></div>
      <svg class="spinner" viewBox="25 25 50 50">
        <circle class="path" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="none" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>

  </app-root>


<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body, html {
      height: 100%;
    }
    .app-loading {
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .app-loading .spinner {
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      animation: rotate 2s linear infinite;
      transform-origin: center center;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
    }
    .app-loading .spinner .path {
      stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
      stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      animation: dash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite;
      stroke-linecap: round;
      stroke: #ddd;
    }
    @keyframes rotate {
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    @keyframes dash {
      0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
      }
      50% {
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: -35px;
      }
      100% {
        stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
        stroke-dashoffset: -124px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Comment: See that any clever way to do it is okay. I have just used "loading..." and it works. The solution proposed works on the app they present, but I was unable to replicate. It would interesting if someone actually teach how they did it, which is awesome!

Comment: Thanks, it worked!!! http://pedecabra.ideacodinglab.com/